# cast_shadow unchecked causes crash

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

### I'm using gazebo 1.2.5 in gentoo linux.  When I run gazebo with default world and add a cylinder and uncheck the cast_shadow property in somewhere in the link section of the cylinder, it causes gazebo to crash with the following error message:

Exception [Publisher.cc:79] Publishing and uninitialized message on topic[/gazebo/default/model/modify]. Required field [link[0].visual[0].name] missing.

Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

### terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'

It happens every time.  GDB shows no backtrace.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/245/cast_shadow-unchecked-causes-crash/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2012-11-21**:
Is anybody else experiencing this bug?

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2012-11-26**:
is this fixed in the dev branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is the same issue: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/180/crash-when-changing-dimensions-of-box.

There is a section of code in the GUI which needs to be fixed, and this is part of it. Follow the above ticket for updates.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0